# Unhandled exception , access violation in opencv cvCaptureFromCAM using Visual c++

Tags: visual-c++, opencv, webcam

I am trying to build a program in Opencv that captures a video and saves it to a file. However, after repeated efforts I continue to get this error : Unhandled exception at 0x201e8efb in basic.exe: 0xC0000005 Access violation, where basic.cpp is my file name.
The same occurs when trying to capture an image.
I have already tried changing cvCaptureFromCAM parameters to CV_CAP_ANY/0/-1/-2/1/2..but none of these worked out.My webcam, works perfectly well for others applications and i have tested it online.
Any help would be greatly appreciated .Thanks in advance.

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include "C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\core.hpp"
#include "C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp"
#include <iostream>
 using namespace cv;

 using namespace std;

void main( ){

    CvCapture *capture = cvCaptureFromCAM( 0 );
    int width = ( int )cvGetCaptureProperty( capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH );
    int height = ( int )cvGetCaptureProperty( capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT );
    CvVideoWriter *writer = cvCreateVideoWriter( "myCamCapture.avi", -1, 30, cvSize( width, height ) );
    cvNamedWindow("camopen", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    IplImage *frame = 0;

    while( 1 )
    {
        frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );
        cvShowImage("d",frame);
        cvWriteFrame( writer, frame );
        char c = cvWaitKey( 30 );
        if( c == 27 ) break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

please, since you're a beginner, *don't* start with the deprecated c-api, use the c++ one instead.

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    VideoCapture cap(0);
    while( cap.isOpened() )
    {
        Mat frame;
        if ( ! cap.read(frame) )
            break;
        imshow("lalala",frame);
        int k = waitKey(10);
        if ( k==27 )
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

regarding your error: please triple-check the libs you're linking (compiler version, debug/release, 32/64bit). you're not allowed to mix different settings there

Comment: Sir, I tried the above code but I get the same exception as mentioned earlier : "Unhandled exception and access violation" .I am new to Opencv. I have tried this in both VS 10 and VS 12 and get this same exception in both. All additional libraries are linked in project settings and build is in debug mode.The same project when run on another laptop works perfectly well. Any more help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just to inform, the codes like displaying of an image or video file work perfectly well.Only those accessing the camera give this exception. Do i need to make some changes in the settings of my integrated webcam.If yes, how ? I am using Windows 8 on Dell Inspiron 15